# How to increment and print a serialized bar code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a bar code program sometime ago with vb.net that when the end user clicks the print button, the program will open the text file that contains the ZPL bar code, increment the serial number by 1, write the new serial number back to the text file, and then print out the predetermined amount of bar codes to a zebra printer.

Now I am trying to rewrite the code so that it will print the number of bar codes the end user wants from the number they type into the PrintDialog. In my updated code, I tried putting in a DO UNTIL ......LOOP.  It will print out the number of bar codes the user puts into the PrintDialog box, but it doesn't serialize. By that I mean if the user enters 5  into the PrintDialog, the program will print serial # 01 five times instead of printing 02, 03, 04, 05, 06.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to have the program read, write, and print the desired x amount of times based on the number  a user inputs into the PrintDialog?

Here is my original code:

```
     Dim sL() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Labels\loop test.txt")
     Dim CurrentBar(2) As String

        For i = 0 To 2
            CurrentBar(i) = sL(sL.Length - 3 + i)
        Next

       If CurrentBar(1).Length >= 28 Then

            CurrentBar(1) = CurrentBar(1).Substring(0, 18) & Format(CInt(CurrentBar(1).Substring(18, 10) + 1), "0000000000") & CurrentBar(1).Substring(28)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("String is not long enough!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

        'Write the updated vaules back to the Text File
        IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Labels\loop test.txt",
        CurrentBar(0) & vbNewLine &
        CurrentBar(1) & vbNewLine &
        CurrentBar(2))

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
            psi.UseShellExecute = True
            psi.Verb = "print"
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden                
            psi.FileName = "C:\Labels\loop test.txt"
            Process.Start(psi)
```

And here is my updated code:

```
    Dim PrintDialog1 As New PrintDialog()
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim sL() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Labels\loop test.txt")
    Dim CurrentBar(2) As String


        Do Until PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.Copies - 1
        For i = 0 To 2
            CurrentBar(i) = sL(sL.Length - 3 + i)
        Next

        If CurrentBar(1).Length >= 28 Then

            CurrentBar(1) = CurrentBar(1).Substring(0, 18) & Format(CInt(CurrentBar(1).Substring(18, 10) + 1), "0000000000") & CurrentBar(1).Substring(28)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("String is not long enough!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

        'Write the updated vaules back to the Text File
        IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Labels\loop test.txt",
        CurrentBar(0) & vbNewLine &
        CurrentBar(1) & vbNewLine &
        CurrentBar(2))

        'Print the labels

        'Get the number of copies to print  
        If (PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then



        'print desired number of copies to target printer
        For I = 0 To PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.Copies - 1

            psi.UseShellExecute = True
            psi.Verb = "print"
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
            psi.FileName = "C:\Labels\loop test.txt"
            Process.Start(psi)
        Next
    End If
  Loop
```

And here is my text file:

```
    ^XA
    ^LH20,85^BY3^AE^SN0000000001R,,Y^B3N,,60,,Y^FS
    ^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in your new code is that you are reading in the text file before you do the loop. At the end of the loop, you write out the new values, but never read them back in (or reuse them). Therefore, the input is always going to be what it was before the loop iterates.  I think by putting

```
sl() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Labels\loop test.txt")
```

right after your Do Until statement should fix this.

Comment: APrough I did try your suggestion, but unfortunately that didn't solve it. I think you are right in about the code is only reading, writing once in the loop before printing the text file.